# After BitTorrent installation (on Windows 10) the Firefox default page and browser become Bing and I cant change it, why?

Tags: windows, windows-10, firefox, browser, bittorrent

I am a Windows 10 user and I have the following problem.

After installing BitTorrent when I open **FireFox** the default page and the default search engine is **Bing**. I tried to switch again setting **Google** as default page and default browsert but after some time automatically it switch back to **Bing**.

What can I try to do to avoid this annoying behavior and have again **Google** as default page and default search engine?

In Chrome seems that I have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes most likely you've got adware. The best way is to easily [reset Mozilla Firefox](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/reset-firefox-settings/) to default settings. If your default search engine or homepage has been changed, you are having adware or pop-up ads problems with Mozilla Firefox, resetting it can help. The reset feature fixes many issues by restoring Firefox to its factory default state while saving your essential information like bookmarks and open tabs. And if not effective, try to uninstall Bittorrent and Mozilla and get another one that is better than before. Use their official to keep safe.

Answer (score -1):

You probably have some type of malware that got installed along with the BitTorrent client. Most likely it's a browser hijacker and meant to redirect your traffic.

Multiple Malwarebytes scans should take care of the issue.

Comment: not exactly malware, adware

Comment: To add to this answer: AdwCleaner will help with this as well.